# Android Espresso: How to test whether a button click migrates to a new screen?

Tags: android, android-espresso

```java
onView(withId(R.id.BUTTON))
    .perform(click())
    .check(matches(withContentDescription(R.id.my_layout)));
onView(withId(R.id.tp_layout))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

I am trying to test whether button click migrates to next screen or not..
how can I match, with this only first test is running and it displays tests failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Espresso extension - Espresso-Intents.

[Here is the official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents).

Quick quote:

> Espresso-Intents is an extension to Espresso, which enables validation
> and stubbing of intents sent out by the application under test. It’s
> like Mockito, but for Android Intents.
>
> If your app delegates functionality to other apps or the platform, you
> can use Espresso-Intents to focus on your own app's logic while
> assuming that other apps or the platform will function correctly. With
> Espresso-Intents, you can match and validate your outgoing intents or
> even provide stub responses in place of actual intent responses.

Comment: Link broken so answer is broken.  Put your answer in, link answers are bad format.